# Arbitrary File Overwrite: tar npm audit

Tags: npm, audit

It said,

```
found 4 high severity vulnerabilities in 891002 scanned packages
  4 vulnerabilities require manual review. See the full report for details.
```

how to make 0 vulnerabilities?

I also do "npm audit fix" and I put "--force", but it didn't work.

and, 
when I do "npm audit",

```
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ High          │ Arbitrary File Overwrite                                     │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ tar                                                          │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=4.4.2                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ npm                                                          │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ npm > libcipm > npm-lifecycle > node-gyp > tar               │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://npmjs.com/advisories/803                             │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ High          │ Arbitrary File Overwrite                                     │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ tar                                                          │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=4.4.2                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ npm                                                          │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ npm > libnpm > npm-lifecycle > node-gyp > tar                │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://npmjs.com/advisories/803                             │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ High          │ Arbitrary File Overwrite                                     │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ tar                                                          │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=4.4.2                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ npm                                                          │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ npm > node-gyp > tar                                         │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://npmjs.com/advisories/803                             │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ High          │ Arbitrary File Overwrite                                     │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ tar                                                          │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=4.4.2                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ npm                                                          │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ npm > npm-lifecycle > node-gyp > tar                         │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://npmjs.com/advisories/803                             │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

And I'm using at react & electron.
when I installed font awesome, this error appeared.
So, I removed the font awesome, but it didn't change anything

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my ionic project. 
[This Link](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2625#issuecomment-482519446) Helped me to get rid this.

In `package-lock.json` replace the following section

```
"version": "2.2.1",
"resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/tar/-/tar-2.2.1.tgz",
"integrity": "sha1-jk0qJWwOIYXGsYrWlK7JaLg8sdE=",
```

with

```
"version": "4.4.8",
"resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/tar/-/tar-4.4.8.tgz",
"integrity": "sha512-LzHF64s5chPQQS0IYBn9IN5h3i98c12bo4NCO7e0sGM2llXQ3p2FGC5sdENN4cTW48O915Sh+x+EXx7XW96xYQ==",
```

Then run

```
sudo rm -fr node_modules
```

and

```
npm install
```

By following this method I got rid of the warnings.

Hope this works for you!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, there's another audit. fstream

Answer (score 0):

for whatever packages you are getting vulnerabilities, change package version inside package-lock.json to the recommended version, remove node_modules and run npm i.

for fstream for e.g :

in package-lock.json from:

```
 "fstream": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/fstream/-/fstream-1.0.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-WvJ193OHa0GHPEL+AycEJgxvBEwyfRkN1vhjca23OaPVMCaLCXTd5qAu82AjTcgP1UJmytkOKb63Ypde7raDIg=="
}
```

to:

```
 "fstream": {
      "version": "1.0.12",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/fstream/-/fstream-1.0.12.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-WvJ193OHa0GHPEL+AycEJgxvBEwyfRkN1vhjca23OaPVMCaLCXTd5qAu82AjTcgP1UJmytkOKb63Ypde7raDIg=="
}
```

delete node_modules:

```
rm node_modules
```

then:

```
npm i
```